# Issues with latin characters using htmlparse in r

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, html-parsing, iso-8859-1

I'm having some encoding problems when trying to webscrape a government page in portuguese. This is my code:

```
library("RCurl")

library("XML")

html = getURL("http://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/institucional/pesquisa/documento_consulta_externa.php?u0r2HDE7WIdiBH3O1y0Dr6krqmN-VVCNjJtZWrdX1mgt3CiIC_RM90F01GwwNk20muowNXaYKrI2Ob8UQUkAoA,,")

par = htmlParse(html)

x = xpathSApply(par, "//strong", xmlValue)[1]

print(x)

[1] "NOTA TÃ‰CNICA NÂº 58/2017/CGAA6/SGA2/SG/CADE"
```

I've tried some things, like adding `encoding="latin1"` and `encoding="UTF-8"` to the `htmlParse`, and adding `.encoding="latin"` and `.encoding="UTF-8"` to the `getURL`.

My system seems to be set to the right location, as Sys.getlocale() gives me

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252"
```

I'm out of ideas here, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using your code with one addition.

```
## Your code
library("RCurl")
library("XML")
html = getURL("http://sei.cade.gov.br/sei/institucional/pesquisa/documento_consulta_externa.php?u0r2HDE7WIdiBH3O1y0Dr6krqmN-VVCNjJtZWrdX1mgt3CiIC_RM90F01GwwNk20muowNXaYKrI2Ob8UQUkAoA,,")
par = htmlParse(html)
x = xpathSApply(par, "//strong", xmlValue)[1]

## Addition
x2 = iconv(x, from="UTF-8", to="latin1")
print(x2)
"NOTA TÉCNICA Nº 58/2017/CGAA6/SGA2/SG/CADE"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that works for me! It's funny how (so far) this has been the only page that's given me this specific problem.